# 'var a' vs 'this.a' in function block

Tags: javascript

I tried to search it on internet but didn't got any answer. Why access of two variables before declaration have two different outputs:

```
function test() {
    console.log(a); // prints 'undefined'.
    console.log(b); // prints 'b is not defined'.
    var a = 5;
    this.b = 10;
}
```

Comment: [variable hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting)

Comment: A block of code does not constitute a question. You should declare the question in there so people can better target their answers.

Comment: @RavinderKumar, you'll want to look at variable hoisting as Darin Dimitrov pointed out. The code is initially ran through for declarations. This allows things like variables and functions to be called prior to them being hit in run-time. Since this.b is an assignment and not a declaration, you end up seeing that it is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

when you write a variable with `var` like `var a` it become a function 
level variable. so now `a` is a variable which is present there before `consol.log(a)` and its not given a value so its `undefined` for b there is no variable defined with name b before it called.

And which all variables are defined with `var` will be function level variable and will be created before anything else in the function. so `a` will be present in the function at the starting itself.

and here `this` will be holding the object of Windows.

Comment: `var a` does *not* create a global variable when used inside a function.

Comment: yes its function level variable

Answer (score 0):

when you declare var variable inside the function then that variable is limited to that function. That mean scope of that variable is limited to that function so you can't access that variable outside of that function.

But if you use this then it can be access through outside but then again you need to create a object of that class/function and access trough it.

```js
function test() { 
    var a = 5;
    this.b = 10;
  
   this.printB = function(){
     return this.b;
    
    }
    
    this.printA = function(){
     return a;
    }
}

var obj = new test();
console.log(obj.a)
console.log(obj.b)
console.log(obj.printA())
console.log(obj.printB())
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all, you are trying to examine the variables **before you declared them**.
This is the correct order:

```
function test()
{
  var a=5;
  this.b=10;

  console.log(a); // Should print 5
  console.log(b); // Should print undefined
  console.log(this.b); // Should print 10
}
```

Second, regarding your question, declaring a `var` inside your function, make is a local private variable inside your function.
declaring `this.b`, will cause `b` to be in a different scope, and `b` for itself as `undefined`. If you want to use `b` inside the function, use `this.b`.

Comment: Whoever downvoted this question should leave a comment explaining the downvote.

Comment: I haven't voted, but this is incorrect. `this.b` does *not* make a local variable.

Comment: @DanielT. - That's not right either. Calling `test()` inside another function does *not* create a variable local to that other function. The example you've shown in your comment would still have `this` as `window` inside `test()`.

Comment: @nnnnnn this.b will print 10, also b will print 10 at console.log

Comment: Because in `test()`, `this` is global... In most other usages of `this`, b wouldn't print 10.

Comment: @nnnnnn Doh yes you're right, my bad.

Comment: @KobyDouek I am intentionally using variables before declaration to know hoisting. Please consider my question as it is. Now tell my why I am getting two different response in case of 'var' and 'this'.

Comment: Becase "b" is not recognized - you never declared "b", you decalred "this.b" - which is in a different scope.

Comment: In that case what is the scope of 'b'?

Comment: this.(variable) is called "Intermediate" scope

Comment: @KobyDouek any link to understand 'Intermediate scope' batter.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript - This explains it well